# Is it possible to delete index of an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I know that following similar thing is possible:-

- to delete a character from an array(by replacing with bblank space)

Comment: Deleting an *index*!?! Arrays are stored in contiguous memory locations, how can you delete an index from somewhere in between that range?

Comment: In java array is of fixed lengths, you cant delete index of aa array

Comment: you should look into ArrayList instead. you could assign null to the index like array[index]=null i suppose. your questions ambiguous.

Comment: Not sure if it accomplishes what you're asking, but you could create a new array, the size being 1 smaller, and add the values you wish to the new array.

Comment: I don't think he really wants to *delete* the index, just replace it by blank space.

Comment: "by replacing with blank space" .. sure, arrays are *mutable* (just not resizable) and thus the elements can be *re-assigned* values ..

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the blank space to the position of the character you want to *replace* - it's not a real deletion, an array in Java is of fixed length (it can't be resized):

```
array[index] = ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete an index from an array. This is because arrays have a fixed length that cannot be changed. If you want a list which you **can** delete elements, check out the ArrayList class. Here is the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Not just Java, you just cannot delete an array's index in any language whatsoever!